# How can I find my R studio 'package' menu bar back

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I have uninstalled my R studio(mac version),when I installed my R studio again, I found the 'package' menu bar was missing
[image]
I have tried to uninstall and install again, but still can't solve the problem. Is there any methods to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Already tried _View > Show Packages_ ?

Comment: @jay.sf yes, but it seems nothing happened.

Comment: Hum, I would delete all rstudio related folders and try installing once again. Not sure on MacOS, under Linux we can find them with `whereis rstudio`. Note that this deletes all rstudio preferences (but not those of R).

Comment: Note, that you may manage your packages independently from rstudio, using `installed.packages()`, `update.packages()`, and `install.packages()`.

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks for your advice! I will have a try

Comment: Have you tried View > Panes > Pane Layout? On the right, is 'Packages' shown and unchecked in one of the quadrants? (I think the default is bottom-right.)

Comment: @Kat,yes I tried. the 'packages' was shown and checked, but the problem still exists.

Comment: You need to check if you have more than one version of R. If you do, which version is RStudio looking for? Is that the same version your library is sitting in? The easiest way to see which version of R RStudio is looking at—when you open RStudio, it's the first line of the standard content that always prints in the console. For the library, type `.Library` in the console, then go to that address in your directory.